# Angular get body from HttpEvent<>

Tags: angular, http, angular-http

I'm performing a get request by calling this method of class `AuthService`:

```
 return this.http.post<any>('url',{
    "username": username,
    "password":password
}, this.httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

from another class:

```
this.authService.login(this.username,this.password).subscribe(response =>{
       console.log("Response " + response.token);
    });
```

The problem here is that `property token does not exist in type HttpEvent<any>`. If I run it and try to print it anyway, it prints correctly, but the error in code remains. I've tried changing type `any` to a custom interface with fields representing my response, but the error is the same because it's always HttpEvent.
How can I solve this?

Comment: In your HttpOptions for the request try adding the `observe: 'response'` key. That will return the full response object instead of the body of the request. Otherwise, please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
this.authService.login(this.username,this.password).subscribe((response : any) =>{
       console.log("Response " + response.token);
    });
```

or if you want to make it typed

```
return this.http.post<{token: string}>('url',{
```

and then

```
this.authService.login(this.username,this.password).subscribe((response : {token: string}) =>{
       console.log("Response " + response.token);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem and found what's going on. Basically the `HttpEvent` type only has a `type` key/attribute/property/you name it.

What you need to do is check into your controller method the type against `HttpEventType.Response`. Then you may cast the `body` property against any interface you need.

Here is my code for you to compare.

> Into my service I prepare HTTP options

```
httpPostOptions: any = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  ),
  observe: 'events'
};
```

> The service method for posting the data

```
sendPostWithResponse(post: IPost): Observable<HttpEvent<IPost>> {
  return this.http.post<IPost>(this.completeUrl, post, this.httpPostOptions);
}
```

> The controller method handling the process

```
this.postService.sendPostWithResponse(data).subscribe({
    next: (httpEvent) => {
      if (httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        let thisPost: IPost = httpEvent.body as IPost;

        let dataMsg = "Id: " + thisPost.id + "\n";
        dataMsg += "User Id: " + thisPost.userId + "\n";
        dataMsg += "Title: " + thisPost.title + "\n";
        dataMsg += "Body: " + thisPost.body + "\n";
        console.log("DATA\n", dataMsg)
      }
    },
    error: (e) => { console.log(e); },
    complete: () => { console.log('COMPLETE'); },
});
```